# Regex for exact match with a variable part

Tags: regex

I have several strings equal to:

```
data-ecommerce-content-id="5d7e7cb9-2f79-454d-9d8f-7a35566a3eb6" data-ecommerce-path="/firstvariable/secondvariable" data-ecommerce-row="1"
```

where `firstvariable` and `secondvariable` contain letters, numbers and "-"

I want to be able to capture:

```
/firstvariable/secondvariable
```

I tried:

```
^data-ecommerce-path=".*("{1})$
```

But it is not outputting any match

(I am using python)

Comment: Take a look at Python's [Regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) again. Hint: I don't think the `^` and `$` characters actually do what you think they do.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
data-ecommerce-path="([^"]+)"
```

(Anchors will only work if you match everything from the start to the end.)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is close.

The `^` character represents the beginning of the string and the `$` character represents the end of the string. Since your desired match is in the middle of the string, you can remove both of those.

Then, to capture just the text in between the double quotes, try this: `"(.*?)"`

Your full pattern should look like this: `data-ecommerce-path="(.*?)"`

Then your desired text is going to be in capture group 1. Something like: `match.group(1)`